# SharePoint 2013: Custom result source not showing up in the webservice method GetPortalSearchInfo result

Tags: 2013, search

I have created my own result source which should be used during the search at some point (via webservice and using the method Query). Settings I used when creating this result source are:
- Protocol "SharePoint local"
- Type "SharePoint-Search results"
- Query transformation left by default for the moment
- Login information "Standard authentication"

After calling GetPortalSearchInfo(), I do not get my new result source. This is the XML I am getting as a response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <SiteConfigInfo xmlns="urn:Microsoft.MSSearch.Response.Config">
    <Name>SharePoint 2013 Test-Umgebung</Name>
    <Id>{dbdc8f94-159e-4eeb-a6d6-6825366151fa}</Id>
    <Scopes>
      <Scope>
        <Name>Personen</Name>
      </Scope>
      ...
    </Scopes>
</SiteConfigInfo>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?